# Why is my image that is displayed on my website not disappearing when I click on a button using several functions I have written?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my program, I wrote several functions so that when you typed any number of ticket holders and complementary passes from 1 to 550, and after that, when you clicked on the button "Calculate Available Seats", it would display : "The number of available seats is " and then 555 minus the number of ticket holders and complementary passes. In addition, I also wanted the image of the airplane below to disappear as soon as I click on the "Calculate Available Seats" button. As a result, I use jQuery (because my teacher wanted me to) to make the image disappear when I clicked on that button, which is this:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    $('#airbus').hide();
});
```

However, when I loaded the webpage and tested it, the image would not disappear when I clicked on the "Calculate Available Seats" button. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my airbus.js file:

```
var name = "Michael Bao";
var copyrightdate = 2016;

function copyright() {
    console.log(name, copyrightdate);
}

var TicketHolders1 = document.getElementById("txtTickets");
var ComplementaryPasses1 = document.getElementById("txtPasses");

function number_of_available_seats(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses) {
      var answer = 555 - (parseInt(TicketHolders) + parseInt(ComplementaryPasses));
        return("The number of available seats is " + answer);
    }

    function showresults(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = number_of_available_seats(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses);
    }

    var button = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");

    function clickonbutton(){
     var TicketHolders = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtTickets").value) || 0;
     var ComplementaryPasses = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtPasses").value) || 0;
     showresults(TicketHolders, ComplementaryPasses);
    }

    button.onclick = function() {
    clickonbutton();
    };

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
        $('#airbus').hide();
    });


TicketHolders1.onblur = function() {
    if (TicketHolders1.value == "") {
        TicketHolders1.value = 0;
    }
};

ComplementaryPasses1.onblur = function() {
    if (ComplementaryPasses1.value == "") {
        ComplementaryPasses1.value = 0;
    }
};
```

And here is my airbus.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- airbus.html -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Airbus Seat Calculator</title>
<style>
DIV.movable { position:absolute;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

  <h2>Airbus Seat Calculator</h2>

  <form id="formTest" method="get" action="processData">
    <table>

    <tr>
      <td><label for="txtTickets">Ticket Holders<span class="inputs"></span></label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtTickets" name="tickets"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="txtPasses">Complementary Passes<span class="inputs"></span></label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="txtPasses" name="passes"></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
          <input type="button" value="Calculate Available Seats" id="btnSubmit"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
<img id="airbus" src="images/airbus.png" />

<div id="results">  
</div>
<h2>Michael Bao
    2016</h2>
<script src="airbus.js">


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have not included jquery.js on your page. JQuery functions won't work without that...

Comment: your code ran as expected in jsfiddle. However I also think same as @nnnnnn that you might have missed to include jquery library in your script. See if any js error is showing in console when you click the button.

Comment: Should I then make a new .js file and called it jquery.js and place the jquery code in there and then put that as a source in my html file?

Comment: jquery.js needs to contain the jQuery library code, not your code. You can download a copy of jquery.js from [the jQuery website](http://jquery.com/download/). Or you can directly link to a copy that is provided by a CDN by adding the following to your html page *before* your own script: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Ohhhhh, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your jquery event listeners inside

> $( document ).ready(function() {
>
> });

try the below code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
      $('#airbus').hide();
   });
});
```

Comment: The OP includes the JS at the end of the body, after the elements in question, so a document ready handler isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  User `.classList.toggle`.

```js
var pic = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    pic.classList.toggle('hide');
});
```

```css
img{
  height: 48px;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/android.svg" alt="test">
<button>Test</button>
```

Comment: *Q. Why doesn't my jQuery `.click()` and `.hide()` work?* A. Use a completely different non-jQuery technique instead. (Um...)

Comment: @nnnnnn jQuery is JavaScript.  My answer can co-exist with jQuery script.

Comment: The question explicitly states that the OP has been asked by his teacher to do this with jQuery, and he asks why his jQuery code doesn't work. (Of course there's no point using jQuery for just this one thing when the rest of his script works without it, but still that is the explicit requirement here.)